# How to redirect outgoing url

Tags: networking, proxy

I have devices on local network that are trying to open an urls which I'd like to redirect to a different urls – a local or public ones.

The only configurable option I've got on those devices is some basic network settings including connection via proxy.

I am blocking the access to that urls with tinyproxy-ogra on a raspi but cannot find a way of redirecting or rewriting it.

Is there any linux or macos software that can do that?

Comment: Can you change the DNS settings on these devices to point to your local DNS server?

Comment: Yes I have a local DNS as well... wait a minute, I think I start to grasp it... :-)